# Cannot save data c# Windows Application

Tags: c#, database, windows

here is my code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database_POS.sdf";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText= "INSERT INTO Customer (Email) Values (@email);";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",textBox_Email.Text);

                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            }
        }

        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

here is my design

[image]

```
    I am only trying to save 'email' here.
```

Here is my sql table, problem is I can not even save a single field into table .

[image]

Database Design
[image]

Now error is this

[image]

Comment: what error your getting here..

Comment: Is `connectionString` correct , have you trace using break point ?

Comment: are you getting a value for textbox_Email.text when you pass it to command.parameters.addwithvalue() ? How did you get the other values into the database

Comment: here is my connection string       <add name="DatabaseConnectionString"
    connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database_POS.sdf"
    providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />

Comment: No problem in your code. But there are a lot of problems in your design! Does your table have a primary key? The `Id` field doesn't look like a primary key because it is nullable. Without a primary key how are you going to identify your records?

Comment: By "design" I don't mean the design of the form! I mean *database design* and *program design*.

Comment: fixed my table, now have Primary Key and Not Null

Comment: That's good :) Then you need to update your code to also insert the primary key, or make the primary key an "identity" column.

Comment: Primary key is now identity and checked the database under Document/visual studion 2010/project_name/bin/ and still not added yet :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41593/discussion-between-wayne-tun-myint-and-md-unicorn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks everyone for answers

[Cannot connect to local database in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840684/cannot-connect-to-local-database-in-c-sharp)

I got my answer form above link.

I am using Compact Database and Trying to connect like SQLServer.

Now got it working.

here is the answer text ,that solve my question

```
When using a .sdf file (SQL Server Compact Edition), you need to use SqlCeConnection and not SqlConnection (that works against a full SQL Server):
```

Answer (score 1):

Some things to check:

1. Do you event get an error? If yes, what is the error? Be aware that you are writing the error message to the Console window, but your application is a Windows Application. Does your application have a Console window? If no, check the Output window in Visual Studio. Or simpler yet, use `MessageBox.Show` to show the error.
2. If program runs without any error, check the return value of `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`. It tells you how many records affected. If it is more that zero, the value is really being stored in the database.
3. Make sure that you are seeing the contents of the database file that you are inserting to in your program! You may have opened `Database_POS.sdf` from your project directory, but the program inserts the data into another `Database_POS.sdf` in your "bin\Debug" directory.

-- More Help --

Change your method to:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database_POS.sdf";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText= "INSERT INTO Customer (Email) Values (@email);";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",textBox_Email.Text);

            connection.Open();
            var rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if(rowsAffected > 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Data inserted successfully");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing inserted into the database!");
        }
    }

    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); // for debugging purpose
    }
}
```